# Microsoft Graph hostedContents id contains a slash

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

The endpoint for retrieving [hosted content bytes for an image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessagehostedcontent-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-get-hosted-content-bytes-for-an-image) is

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{id}/messages/{id}/hostedContents/{id}/$value
```

However, the `id` for `hostedContents` items is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table) encoded. For those `id`s that contain a slash (`/`), the request fails with 400. Encoding the slash as `%2f` also fails with 400.  Switching the slash to `_` or `-` results in 404.

How can I retrieve `hostedContents` bytes for an image when the id contains a slash?

Comment: We're also running into this issue, we're currently investigating some encoding workarounds. I'll post an answer if we find anything....

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work you will need to double encode and use `%252F` instead when dealing with the Microsoft Graph API:

```
encodeURIComponent(string).replace(/%2F/g, "%252F");
```

This should work for any value that has a `/` including ID's.

I go into a bit more detail on this Github issue (to get the docs fixed):

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10167